# Sum of two measurable functions is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Royden when $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, then $f+g$ is measurable.

For $x \in E$ if $f(x)+g(x) < c$, then $f(x) < c - g(x)$. By the density of the rational numbers, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$f(x) < q < c - g(x)$.

Hence, $\{x \in E : f(x) + g(x)< c\} = \displaystyle\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} [ \{x \in E: g(x)<c-q\}\cap\{x \in E: f(x)<q\}]$.

I understand almost everything, but I don't understand why we need to use the $\bigcup$ of rational numbers. i.e., I understand that we need to use a rational number in the equation to proof each part is measurable. But why to use the union of the sets that meet the conditions for every rational number? Is not enough to meet just one national number?

Comment: A countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Thank you. But why we need in the poof the union? If every set is measurable it Is obvious that the union is measurable (by definition of sigma-algebra). So I don't understand why we need to proof that.

Comment: For each $q \in \Bbb Q$, $\{x \in E : g(x)<c-q\}$ and $\{x \in E : f(x)<q\}$ are two measurable subsets of $E$ (because $f$ and $g$ are measurable), and then so is $\{x \in E : g(x)<c-q\} \cap \{x \in E : f(x)<q\}$. It follows that $\{x \in E : f(x)+g(x)<c\}$ is measurable as is a countable union of measurable sets.

Comment: Thank you, azif00, but why that set is equal to a union? Why not just say for some $q \in Q $. It is necessary to show that it is a countable union of measurable sets? thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if you say that $\{x \in E : f(x)+g(x)<c\} = \{x \in E : g(x)<c-q\} \cap \{x \in E : f(x)<q\}$ for some $q \in \Bbb Q$, which one? I don’t think you can find such $q$.

Comment: Ok, azif0, I think I got it. Thank you very much. If you want to,  post your answer to choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For some" is another way to say "union".

$$
\{x : x \in A_q \text{ for some }q \in \mathbb Q\}
= \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} A_q .
$$

Similarly, "for all" is another way to say "intersection".

$$
\{x : x \in A_q \text{ for all }q \in \mathbb Q\}
= \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb Q} A_q .
$$